# MDX DateAdd function over a set of tuples

Tags: set, tuples, mdx, dateadd

I am trying to create a set of dates using `DateAdd()` function but I am getting errors while trying to pass a set of tuples as parameter.
The below code returns a member but I am looking for a set of new dates.

> WITH 
>       Member [EFF INJ DT] AS 
>       DATEADD("M",12, [INJURY DATE].CurrentMember)
>
> ```
> SELECT {[EFF INJ DT]} ON COLUMNS, [INJURY DATE].[DATE].Members ON ROWS
> FROM [WVWC DATA CUBE FROI SROI]
> ```

I have the following attempt:

> ```
>  WITH 
> Set [EFF INJ DT] AS 
> DATEADD("M",12, [INJURY DATE].CurrentMember)
>
> SELECT {[EFF INJ DT]} ON COLUMNS, [INJURY DATE].[DATE].Members ON ROWS
> FROM [WVWC DATA CUBE FROI SROI]
> ```

Comment: Please specify the set of dates you require?

Comment: What makes you think that `DATEADD` is an MDX function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Adv Works if you want to move 12 members forward then you can navigate in several ways.

Try the following. It should return the date 12 days ahead of the `currentmember`:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT] AS
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.LEAD(12).MEMBERVALUE
SELECT 
    {[MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT]}  ON 0,
    {[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[4].CHILDREN} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Looks like you want to return the date which is 12 *months* in the future.

So first we need the year that corresponds to the `currentmember` via the `ANCESTOR` function > then go forward to the equivalent date using the `COUSIN` function like the following:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT] AS
    COUSIN(
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember, 
        ANCESTOR(
            [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember, 
            [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]).LEAD(1)
            ).membervalue   
SELECT 
    {[MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT]}  ON 0,
    {[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[4].CHILDREN} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Adapting to your scenario and assuming that `INJURY DATE` is a multi-level `user hierarchy' that contains another level called`Calendar Year` you could do the following:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT] AS
        COUSIN(
            [INJURY DATE].CurrentMember, 
            ANCESTOR(
                [INJURY DATE].CurrentMember, 
                [INJURY DATE].[Calendar Year]).LEAD(1)
                ).MEMBERVALUE   
SELECT 
    {[MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT]}  ON 0,
    {[INJURY DATE].[DATE].Members} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

**EDIT**

Via the `VBA` tools we have the following in Adv Wrks:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT] AS
      DATEADD(
      "M",
      12,
      [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.membervalue 
      )  
SELECT 
    {[MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT]}  ON 0,
    {[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[4].CHILDREN} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Adapted to your scenario:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT] AS
    DATEADD(
    "M",
    12,
    [INJURY DATE].CurrentMember.membervalue 
    )  
SELECT 
    {[MEASURES].[EFF INJ DT]}  ON 0,
    {[INJURY DATE].[DATE].Members} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Thanks whytheq for the quick response. The code that you provided doesn't serve my purpose. It gives me the date which is the next member from current date, but i am looking for date which is exactly 12 months ahead of current time. In my [Injury Date] dimension there are gaps between years (1920,1921, 1924,1930,1931 etc.)
So, this code gives me the next dates from current date (i.e. after 1924 it gives 1930) while I need 1925.
That's why I was trying to do a DateAdd()..

Comment: You can start playing around with strings and `VBA` functions within 'MDX' - here is a reference to start you of: (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/71c81d1b-323e-48ef-a183-1b53ca2eb33d/dateadd-datepart-in-mdx?forum=sqlanalysisservices) Might be easier to create a linked server between SSAS and SQL-Server and then use T-SQL function `OPENQUERY` to pull the data over to sql and then start playing around with it.

Comment: (p.s. gaps in a date dimension is exceptionally bad design)

Comment: i know it would have been a lot easier if i had the whole calendar, but i am working with injury dates only so there are gaps. i have already tried to implement the VBA date functions but still haven't yet figured out the right solution.

Comment: I have got my solution now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes its quite similar to what you suggested

Comment: (You could always mark my post as the answer - or maybe up the post to show appreciation for the time I spent on it. Although no problem if you don't want to)

Comment: sorry whytheq, i am new around here :) i really appreciated your help.

Comment: i see. now i have +2 reputation. Thanks!

Comment: @pso I know - not a massive win but better than -2

Comment: So it must have taken you quite a while to get all that points?