# Getting getdate(), datediff in SSAS (MDX) query

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012

We have a MDX query which looks like this:

```
WITH Member [Measures].[Z] AS (DATEADD("H",-1,[X].[Y].Member_Caption)) 
SELECT { [X].[Y].Children } ON Rows,
       { [Measures].[Z] } ON Columns
FROM ABC
```

It basically returns Datetime (LastRefresh).

My task is to create an MDX query that returns the following columns:

```
LastRefresh, Getdate(), datediff(Mins, LastRefresh, Getdate())
```

Its equivalent SQL query is:

```
select LastRefresh, getdate() as CurrentDate, datediff(Mins, LastRefresh, getdate()) as DateDifference from XYZ
```

How can I do the same in MDX on the Cube?

## Note:

We can't create any new measures, as we are just using the Cube to get data, and don't have any kind of access to create measures etc.

Comment: what is your question? I cannot see a question mark anywhere.

Comment: We need to mimic the SQL query in mdx

Comment: LastRefresh is not available via mdx against the cube (unless you've added a Last Refresh member somewhere?!)

Comment: We have lastRefreshMember,I want getdate() and differnce on the same

Comment: [X].[Y].Children This gives out lastrefresh

Comment: does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629814/mdx-dateadd-function-over-a-set-of-tuples  or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479968/mdx-where-date-is-less-than-now

Answer (score 0):

`GETDATE()` is a SQL function, but you are writing MDX, so it is not allowed.

If you are using Microsoft SSAS then VBA is allowed within MDX, and you can use `Now()` to return the current date and time.

Use the VBA format of `DateDiff` (not the SQL version!) and you can do the calculation that way. You probably need `CDate()` to turn the string value of a member name into a date object for VBA to use. Such as...

```
DateDiff("d", CDate([X].[Y].MemberName), Now())
```